# Не стартуют воркеры unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня появилась проблема с автозапуском *unicorn-воркеров*. В логе вижу:

> WARN: unicorn start command exited with non-zero code = 127

Однако, если я сделаю `god status` получаю

```
unicorn: up
unicorn_rails: up
```

В процессах *воркеров* нет. Если я делаю запуск руками `god -c /etc/god/god.rb -D`, всё стартует и работает.Есть аналогичный сервер и на нем всё стартует нормально.

Как добиться автозапуска?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема запуска была в не верном runlevel автозапуска god. Пришлось удалить и снова добавить в атозапуск god. были косяки с k80, s20, и тд. /etc/rc0,1,2,3,4,5,6.d.